# Is n-dimensional hypervolume different from n-dimensional state space?

Tags: terminology, definition, state-space-models, ecology

Is there any difference between Hypervolumes (e.g. Blonder et al., 2014; Barros et al., 2016) and state spaces (sensu von Bertalanffy, 1972; e.g. Tett et al., 2013)? If so, what is it?

It seems that these are essentially the same thing, but the surplus of definitions is confusing.

*Reference*:

Barros, C., Thuiller, W., Georges, D., Boulangeat, I. and Münkemüller, T. (2016), N-dimensional hypervolumes to study stability of complex ecosystems. Ecol Lett, 19: 729-742. https://doi.org/10.1111/ele.12617

Blonder, B., Lamanna, C., Violle, C. and Enquist, B.J. (2014), The n-dimensional hypervolume. Global Ecology and Biogeography, 23: 595-609. https://doi.org/10.1111/geb.12146

Von Bertalanffy, L. (1972). The History and Status of General Systems Theory. The Academy of Management Journal, 15(4), 407-426. doi:10.2307/255139

Tett P, Gowen RJ, Painting SJ, Elliott M and others (2013) Framework for understanding marine ecosystem health. Mar Ecol Prog Ser 494:1-27. https://doi.org/10.3354/meps10539

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the first references paper, *N-dimensional hypervolumes to study stability of complex ecosystems*, hypervolumes is used as a kind of descriptive statistic in ecology. They are looking at (nonlinear) dynamical models in ecology, describing time trajectory of an ecosystem. Such a model has an $n$-dimensional state space, and some specific $n$-region in that space where the system tends to stay (maybe an attractor).

This region is then called a *hypervolume*, although that term is more typically used for a measure of its size, called volume in traditional geometry. In this sense *length* is 1-volume, *area* is 2-volume and so on, see also [Hypervolume concepts in niche- and trait-based ecology](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ecog.03187).

Then the state of an ecosystem before and after some intervention (like change in land use or tempearture increase or ...) can be coursely described by comparing their hypervolumes, for instance their *size*, degree of overlap, ...

So, back to your question, state space and hypervolume is **not** the same thing, but a hypervolume is a specific region in a state space.

Comment: Thank you! this is very helpful and makes perfect sense.